# should we manully clear out the "Workflow History" list inside our online sharepoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, administration, workflow2013

We have two 2013 workflows inside our SharePoint online site collection. The number of items in the "Workflow History" list is now 4,800 items, so the list is near to reaching the threshold.

Will this list clear itself? Or do we need to manage this manually and remove some items from it?  Does it matter if the threshold is exceeded?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint will not delete entries out of the History List on its own -- however, when this list inevitably exceeds the List View Threshold, it will not break any of the history lists displayed on Workflow status.  You will only run into a problem if your users navigate to and view that list directly.  If you are only interacting with the list through its association with workflows and built-in workflow screens, you never have to worry about the list view threshold of this list.

Answer (score 2):

The list will not be cleared automatically.

You need to delete those items manually or maybe using any script.

**Note**: If you have any extra "log to history list" actions in your workflow then you can delete them once you are done with development and workflow is live.

**Script References**:

1. [Purge SharePoint Workflow History List](http://www.softlanding.ca/about-Softlanding/resources/blog/purge-sharepoint-workflow-history-list).
2. [Maintain SharePoint Workflow History Lists](https://www.thelazyspadmin.com/maintain-sharepoint-workflow-history-lists/).

Comment: My live workflow logs the actions it do, so users can check what the workflow did. so i need to keep those logs

Comment: Yes, but there might be chances that you have added some logs just for verification purpose while development. This is common scenario. So, I am just suggesting to remove those extra actions (if you have any).